# Eclipse Microprofile and Jakarta EE 9

Tags: jakarta-ee, microprofile

2020 brought us Microprofile 4.0 and Jakarta EE 9. However I was surprised that Microprofile 4 still aligned with Jakarta EE 8 (although it was released at the same time as Jakarta EE 9).
I couldn't find any plans/schedule about Eclipse Microprofile migration to Jakarta EE 9.
So should we expect this happen in 2021? The fact that Microprofile still uses 8th version slows down adoption of Jakarta EE 9 (and upcoming 10th release this year).

Answer (score 1):

For a platform/profile that in principle should be ahead of Jakarta EE in order to experiment with the latest technology it's indeed a somewhat conservative choice to stay at Java EE 8 (not even Jakarta EE 8 at the moment).

MicroProfile however was late with officially adopting Java EE 8 as well, and was solely Java EE 7 for a long time.

Looking at the speed of adoption before and based on some conversations about this my guess would be this is considered for the October release of MP this year.

Comment: wow. does this mean that if we have apps we want to migrate to jakarta 9 but require MP it will nt be possible before 9 months at least ("...would be considered...in October)? wow. OpenLiberty has most of jakarta 9 packages in 20.0.0.2-beta and also MP 4.0 packages but  currrently you can not use both (or any version of MP) because of MP dependencies... my feeling ois that it will take years before being able tu use jakarta 9+ with MP